# How to pull an older version from git

Tags: github

I created a bare minimum project on laravel and pushed it on my github repo. I made some changes on the version i'm working on pc but didn't commit them. Now i want to pull the bare minimum version back from git. I don't want to save the changes i have made. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This git command will discard local changes to all files, permanently:
`git reset --hard`

Comment: i tried this but apprently `git stash` worked

Comment: Yep!.  `git stash` works as well...  That command actually saves (or *stashes*) the changes that you made locally for later retrieval if you so desire.  You can type:
`git stash list` for a summary of what was stashed
`git stash show` will print out the details of what was stashed